# Prime Factorization in Python

Tags: python

I found this piece of code online and it basically functions by factorizing a given number into its prime factors and lists them.

```
def primefactors(x):
factorlist=[]
loop=2
while loop<=x:
    if x%loop==0:
        x/=loop
        factorlist.append(loop)
    else:
        loop+=1
return factorlist
```

Now I understand this code works in general. It takes the number 'loop' starting from 2 and looks to see if it can be divided into the number x. If yes, then it adds to the list and if not, 1 is added and the process is repeated.  However I am unsure of this part.

```
x/=loop
```

What does this operator '/=' do and how does it prevent larger non prime numbers from appearing in the list?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: `/=` divides the LH by the RH and places the result in the LH. i.e., `X/=3` divides X by 3 then places the result in X.

Comment: `x /= loop` is the same as writing `x =  x / loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x /= loop` is equivalent to `x = x / loop`.

Since you are dividing x by `loop` until loop is no longer a factor of x, by the time you get to any composite number, you'll have already divided out all of its prime factors, so the composite number will not be a factor of the current value of x.

Answer (score 0):

/= Divide AND

It divides left operand with the right operand and assign the result to left operand

example : 
c /= a is equivalent to c = c / ac /= a is equivalent to c = c / a