# Is it possible to use prime numbers (not prime factorization), to find GCD?

Tags: python, primes, prime-factoring, greatest-common-divisor

I have a code challenge that asks us to create 3 functions using the previous function. We are using "base python" so no imports. Versions without lambdas would be ideal, but both are welcome.

1. `find_factors` function
2. `is_prime` function - using the `find_factors` function
3. `hcf` function - using the `is_prime` function

The first two functions return the factors and prime numbers and the `is_prime` function is using the `find_factors` function as our instructor asked.

```
def find_factors(num):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if num%i==0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors


def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for a in (find_factors(x):
            if x % a == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Next we were asked to use the `is_prime` function in this `hcf` function to find the HCF. 

How do I use the second `is_prime` function in this third `hcf` function?

```
def hcf(x, y): 
    if x > y: 
        small = y 
    else: 
        small = x 

    for i in range(1, small+1): 
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)): 
            hcf = i   
    return hcf
```

Is it even possible to find HCF from normal primes? Maybe our instructor meant [prime factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898547/prime-factorization-in-python)?

Comment: Is your indentation correct for `find_factors`.  Right now it just returns num.  Is it suppose to return the smallest divisor?  If so, it seems like a misleading name.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure why it is misleading. In the `find_factors` function I input `12` and it spits out `1,2,3,4,6,12`. All the indentation seems to work.

Comment: with your current implementation, it doesn't even return an array! Even you fix the indent, it will return the first divisor.

Comment: I had a print line in there before so that's why the return was where it was. But I put the print back. Do I need it?

Comment: @Edison--the comment by Zabir Al Nazi is what I referred to in my earlier comment.  How could it spit out multiple values when you're not putting items into a list?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Next issue is `for a in range(2,find_factors(x)):` should be `for a in find_factors(x):` with a check for a > 1 and a < x before returning False.  Or it would have been better to define range in find_factors to be `range(2, num)`.  This way you only got factors not including 1 and the number itself.

Comment: Fixed. It ended with the same result but I guess it was more verbose.

Comment: @DarrylG not sure why you deleted your answer. I ran your code in Jupyter and it works great. Other viewers would definitely upvote it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Edison--perhaps but I deleted it when I noticed Zabir Al Nazi answer where he had the simpler max([x for x in divx if x in divy]) to find the highest common point which I liked more than my for loop.  However, I would suggest his/her is_prime should use find_factors.

Comment: Some bugs in the code remain. is_prime always returns false because, even for prime x, 1 and x will be returned by find_factors. The simpler way is simply to note than x is prime if and only if len(prime_factors(x)) == 2. The the `else` branch in is_prime can be simplified to `return len(prime_factors(x)) == 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, your `find_factors` return all the divisor of a number. Then, you can just check the all common divisor for both `x` and `y`, and take the max that would be the divisor. Technically, you don't need the `is_prime` function.

For example,

If we have 12, and 4. Let's find the factors first. We will get them in a sorted manner from find_factors.

12 has factors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12

4 has factors: 1, 2, 4

possible solution set = [1, 2, 4] (the common ones only)

GCD or greatest common divisor will be only the maximum common number from both lists. So, the answer is 4.

```
def find_factors(num):
    divs = []
    for value in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % value == 0:
            divs.append(value)
    return divs

def hcf(x, y):
    divx = find_factors(x)
    divy = find_factors(y)
    pos_sol = set(divx).intersection(divy)
    return max(pos_sol)

print(hcf(56, 12))
```

A simpler version:

```
def find_factors(num):
    divs = []
    for value in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % value == 0:
            divs.append(value)
    return divs

def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for a in range(2,x-1): # technically you can go upto sqrt(n) but if math is allowed 
            if x % a == 0:
                return False
    return True

def hcf(x, y):
    if is_prime(x) and is_prime(y):
        return 1

    divx = find_factors(x)
    divy = find_factors(y)
    pos_sol = [x for x in divx if x in divy]
    return max(pos_sol)

print(hcf(4, 12))
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I had already fixed the find_factors function. Thanks. Ok but for our challenge we are supposed to have three functions. The third hcf function needs to use the is_primes function.

Comment: There is no relation of gcd and being a number prime, but only co-primality matters. Is the hcf has to be only based on is_primt or there can be other checks/looping etc along the is_prime?

Comment: We can write whatever we want as long as we have the three functions and each function uses the previous function. We cannot use imports or advanced syntax because we have not discussed them yet. Just base python. `find_factors`, `is_prime` and `hcf`.

Comment: Did you understand the first implementation? What did you miss? The code or the way the algorithmic thinking was?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi--posted an answer.  Tried to be basic but wasn't sure if you know about slicing arrays.  If not I can change to something more basic.

Comment: Yes. The first two are easy as they are very similar as what I had. The third is more challenging. The algo is a bit over my head but I am studying it. What does `pos_sol` mean?

Comment: `pos_sol` means, possible_solutions. The probable candidates are from the common elements of the two lists. The final answer is the max of them. I added an example to explain things. Maybe that will clear things up.

Comment: @DarrylG All versions are very welcome. Our challenges get more difficult quickly so I love looking at all versions for practicing algos.  I like looking at both side-by-side. It's easier to understand the more complex version that way. Plus many others look at the answers and would benefit from your answer. Cheers. p.s. We are also using slicing so no problem.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Thank you so much. I will understand it by tomorrow :)

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Yes GCD is very easy for me. I could do it without the primes as you can see in my own code. But I did not understand how to use primes to get GCD. I know you are using `if is_prime(x) and is_prime(y): return 1` as a traditional GCD check and swap, but I'm not sure how it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Using is_prime and find_factors for hcf

**Code**

```
def find_factors(num):
  factors = []
  for value in range(1, num + 1):
      if num % value == 0:
        factors.append(value)

  return factors

def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    else:
      # prime if only factors are 1 and itself
      # i.e. length factors equals 2
      return len(find_factors(x))==2 

def hcf(a, b):
  if a == b:
    return a
  elif is_prime(a) and is_prime(b):
    return 1

  # We know factors are in ascending order
  # based upon how the list is generated
  f_a = find_factors(a)
  f_b = find_factors(b)

  for num in f_a[::-1]: # go in reverse order
                        # to get the highestest number first
    if num in f_b:     
      return num        # Found if in other list
```

**Test**

```
for a, b in [(5, 15), (2, 3), (24, 8)]:
    print(f'For {a} & {b}, hcf = {hcf(a, b)}')
```

**Output**

```
For 5 & 15, hcf = 5
For 2 & 3, hcf = 1
For 24 & 8, hcf = 8
```

Comment: Yeah, this is awesome. And as I mentioned, we are using slicing in our course so this is great. I like the simple versions for my mind, and the more advanced versions for the syntax :)  I come from Swift/Obj-C so the syntax is a bit challenging for me.

Comment: @Edison--that's not surprising since a key feature of Swift is it's noted to be easy to read.

Comment: Yes, and Obj-C is completely different syntax. I mean python is easy to read too, but I'm not a senior developer so any small changes throw me off. And I'm not a CS major so algos are not my strongest area. I don't architect algos in development.